# Is it suggested to exchange 1- and 2-star (and even 3-star) Orbs to at least 3 or 4 star orbs asap?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

Once you get to a certain point in the game you more or less stop getting 1 star orbs and start getting mostly 2 and 3 star orbs with the occasional 4 and 5 star orbs. For example I see it is suggested to get Ruinga early on. I do not have 3 4-star Dark Orbs but I do have 30+ 3-star Dark Orbs. I also have more than a few 1-star orbs that I have not used. Is it worth just upgrading them immediately to get the ability or should I just wait until I have to appropriate materials and exchanging is more a personal preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few low-level Abilities that are worth leveling, here are a few (non-exhaustive, just based on my inventory) examples:

- Retaliate and Double Cut form a pretty killer combo
- Boost can be extremely useful for upping the attack of someone with a strong soul break (or your Retaliate/Double Cut target)
- Lower level Cure spells are occasionally useful for a "second tier" healer like Paladin Cecil
- Chi Blast can be good for monks, if you don't have many high-level ranged weapons.  Occasionally a boss can only be hit by ranged attacks.
- Revive is a 2* ability, and has obvious utility

Also bear in mind that in some situations having an honed lower level ability with 6+ charges is better than having just one or two hits of a higher level ability.  Sometimes a battle is more of a marathon and less of a sprint.  Thus, you might be better off honing lower-level abilities now and waiting for higher level orbs to become more common.

Beyond those exceptions, though, I often upgrade my orbs to the highest tier possible.  In the long term, most of the best abilities require the best orbs.